# regexp - replace text outside another text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm editing some C# code, and need to change expressions like nameof(somevar) to "somevar". Is it doable with regexp?

Below is a better example:

What I have:

```
throw new ArgumentException(nameof(outputFilePath));
```

What I need:

```
throw new ArgumentException("outputFilePath");
```

Comment: What is the point and benefit of doing this? The purpose of `nameof` is precisely to make sure that the string produced by `nameof` is actually matching the given member/variable name, in contrast to having a string there that accidentally could contain a wrong/misspelled/old member name...

Comment: I need this for powershell script, and it doesn't support version 6+ features.

Comment: Oh, i see. Well, then there is of course no way around removing this operator... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace regexp:

```
  nameof\(([^)]*)\)
```

by:

```
  "\1"
```

Comment: this example is using notepad++ or other editor when you request replace put this parameters. But using javascript you can use direct:
"throw new ArgumentException(nameof(outputFilePath));".replace(/nameof\(([^)]*)\)/,"\"\$1\"")

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
  string s = "nameof(abc)";
  Regex r = new Regex("nameof\\((.+?)\\)");
  string output = r.Replace(s, "\"$1\"");
```

- `\(` searches for the opening parenthesis
- `(.+?)` creates a group (i.e. `$1`) which searches for any char (`.`) one or more times (`+`), lazily (`?`)
- `\)` searches for the closing parenthesis

Comment: I'm using VS Code to replace it, somehow it's not finding anything for "nameof\\((.+?)\\)". I used @seduardo solution, but  it wouldn't work without $ as  you mentioned, so I'm upvoting your answer )

Comment: @MikeTwc Huh...not sure why it wouldn't work, but I'm glad seduardo's answer did.